# Continuous delivery with docker, nginx and multiple frontend repositories

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, devops, continuous-deployment

What is the right way to build continuous delivery with docker and nginx for multiple sources of files to serve?
My current scheme is building containers with front(gitlab ci/cd), push them to registry, pull on production, up docker compose with mounts from frontend images to nginx.

In this way, I need to make some magic actions to update volumes with images update, like writing file in frontend container command or recreate volumes each deploy, so I suppose this is not the way.

When I had only one frontend to deploy in nginx container was also building frontend, so this was not an issue.

Here is compose for better understanding

```
version: "3.9"

services: 
  frontend_admin:
    image: ${REGISTRY_URL}/admin_front:${VERSION}
    volumes:
      - dist_admin:/app/dist

  frontend_admin:
    image: ${REGISTRY_URL}/front:${VERSION}
    volumes:
      - dist_root:/app/dist

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.9-alpine
    restart: always
    command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - dist_admin:/usr/share/nginx/html/admin:ro
      - dist_root:/usr/share/nginx/html/root:ro

volumes:
  dist_admin:
  dist_root:
```

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose down -v` will reset the volume, and `docker-compose up --build` to build again. Does this work?

Note, however, that resetting volumes may clear any application data you may have, such as database data. So be careful when using it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this kinda solves the problem, but this solution has problems with more complicated schemes, for example docker-compose down also removes network which can be in use by other containers(for example backend that also proxies with nginx) and as you mentioned there can be volumes with actual data. After all I dont want to restart nginx with frontend updates

Comment: Maybe you can try your luck with kubernetes 